# R use unicode character in wordcloud

Tags: r, unicode, word-cloud

I'd like to use a wordcloud where i'd plot some variable modality names, one of this modality is for example:

```
age = [13,43]
```

In the wordcloud i'd like to display instead:

```
age ∈ [13,43]
```

(The ∈ unicode code is U+2208)

I tried the following code:

```
gsub('= \\[', "∈ [", my_modality)
```

But in the plot instead of getting "∈" I get "..."